# Java: Declaring a variable but saying it doesnt exist

Tags: java, action, jframe, listener, handler

I am trying to make a basic calculator (im not done) but im getting an error in which the action listener is saying that the variable "add" doesnt exist. I have parsed everything and such but the variable doesnt seem to be declared properly heres the code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Gui extends JFrame{

    private JButton reg;
    private JButton reg2;
    private JButton reg3;
    private JButton reg4;
    private JTextField text;
    private JTextField text2;
    private JTextField text3;
    private JTextField text4;
    private JTextField text5;
    private JTextField text6;
    private JTextField text7;
    private JTextField text8;


    public Gui(){
        super("Buttons");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());



        text = new JTextField("000000000000000000000");
        text2 = new JTextField("000000000000000000000");
        text3 = new JTextField("000000000000000000000");
        text4 = new JTextField("000000000000000000000");
        text5 = new JTextField("000000000000000000000");
        text6 = new JTextField("000000000000000000000");
        text7 = new JTextField("000000000000000000000");
        text8 = new JTextField("000000000000000000000");
        reg = new JButton("Add");
        reg2 = new JButton("Divide");
        reg3 = new JButton("Multiply");
        reg4 = new JButton("Subtract");

        add(text);
        add(text2);
        add(reg);
        add(text3);
        add(text4);
        add(reg2);
        add(text5);
        add(text6);
        add(reg3);
        add(text7);
        add(text8);
        add(reg4);

        String st = text.getText();
        String st2 = text.getText();
        String st3 = text.getText();
        String st4 = text.getText();
        String st5 = text.getText();
        String st6 = text.getText();
        String st7 = text.getText();
        String st8 = text.getText();

        int txt1 = Integer.parseInt(st);
        int txt2 = Integer.parseInt(st2);
        int txt3 = Integer.parseInt(st3);
        int txt4 = Integer.parseInt(st4);
        int txt5 = Integer.parseInt(st5);
        int txt6 = Integer.parseInt(st6);
        int txt7 = Integer.parseInt(st7);
        int txt8 = Integer.parseInt(st8);

        int add=txt1+txt2;
        if(txt4>0){
            int add2=txt3/txt4;
        }
        int add3=txt5*txt6;
        int add4=txt7-txt8;


        handlerClass handler = new handlerClass();
        reg.addActionListener(handler);
        reg2.addActionListener(handler);
        reg3.addActionListener(handler);
        reg4.addActionListener(handler);






    }

    public class handlerClass implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            if(event.getActionCommand()=="Add"){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("Answer: %s", add));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is the error code

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    add cannot be resolved to a variable

    at Gui$handlerClass.actionPerformed(Gui.java:101)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    add cannot be resolved to a variable

    at Gui$handlerClass.actionPerformed(Gui.java:101)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    add cannot be resolved to a variable

    at Gui$handlerClass.actionPerformed(Gui.java:101)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I realize i dont have anything for the divide, multiply or subtract yet im still working on it

Comment: What is the exact error message and on what line does it happen?

Comment: the error codes to long O.0 about 6k to long

Comment: @AaronLeslie: The error code wouldn't be nearly as long if you hadn't tried to run code which didn't compile. You have an error at *compile time*. You shouldn't be even *trying* to run it in that state.

Comment: Please learn how to use code formatting.  Use it for code and Exception output.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("Answer: %s", add));
```

tries to use `add` as a variable. However, that variable *doesn't exist* in the `actionPerformed` method. It's a *local* variable in the `Gui` constructor. It's slightly confusing as `add` is *also* a method, but fundamentally the problem is that the `add` variable you declared *locally* within the constructor doesn't exist later on.

Also note that this comparison:

```
if(event.getActionCommand()=="Add")
```

*may* work depending on how you're supplying the command, but it's really just comparing `String` *references*. You should use:

```
if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Add"))
```

or if the action command may be null (and you don't want to bother checking):

```
if ("Add".equals(event.getActionCommand())
```

Also note that this:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: add cannot be resolved to a variable

indicates that you've probably *ignored* a warning from Eclipse saying "The code doesn't compile - do you really want to try to run it anyway?"

You shouldn't be trying to run code which doesn't compile - you should *fix the compile-time errors* before trying to run it.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, inside the ActionListener, `add` is not defined. It's a local variable of the Gui constructor.

It's only when the action is performed (i.e. inside the `actionPerformed()` method) that you should read from the textfields and perform the addition. Currently, your code adds what is in the textfields when the Gui is initialized, and you try displaying the result of this initial addition when the action is performed.

Also, instead of comparing button texts inside the actionPerformed method, it would be much cleaner to add a specific ActionListener for each button. Add a listener which adds to the add button; a listener which subtract to the subtract button, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Aaron, believe the compiler.  Your code is wrong, wrong, wrong.

```
public class handlerClass implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        if(event.getActionCommand()=="Add"){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("Answer: %s", add));
        }
    }
}
```

There's no variable named add in the scope of actionPerformed.  The one you declared in the constructor is a local variable that's not visible here.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about `add` then it is because you declared it in constructor

```
public Gui(){
...
    int add=txt1+txt2;
...
}
```

so it is local reference, and you cant use it in other methods or inner classes. Make it class field if you want to use it there.

```
public class Gui extends JFrame{
...
    int add;

    public Gui(){
    ...
        int add=txt1+txt2;
    ...
    }
    public class handlerClass implements ActionListener{
        //now add will be accesible here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should also say `add2` doesn't exist.

Inside the `ActionListener` implementation you don't have access to the local `add` variable declared in your constructor. It should either be an instance variable, a static, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable "add" is declared in the class constructor for Gui, which is never instantiated.  This is a basic issue with the structure of your program and variable scoping.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the variable `add` inside the constructor. This means that `add` is a local variable, visible only inside the constructor.

All you need to do is move the declaration of the variable `add` outside. In other words, make add an instance variable, if you want it to be visible to your nested class.

Now your instance variables will have one more variable like this:

```
private JButton reg;
private JButton reg2;
...
private JTextField text7;
private JTextField text8;


private int add;
```

and the line below, where you assign value to `add` will change from:

```
    int add=txt1+txt6;
```

to

```
    add=txt1+txt2;
```

Note that int you will have to do the same for other variables as well if you want them to be visible to some nested class.